# Invariance of the number of holes

Tags: algebraic-topology, intuition, homology-cohomology

Suppose that $\Omega$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. What conditions on $\Omega$ ensure that $\Omega_k$ homeomorphic to $\Omega_l$ implies $k=l$, where $\Omega_k$ denotes $\Omega$ with any $k$ points removed. I know it to be true for $\Omega=\mathbb{R}^2$ (consider the first betti number), but what about the more general situation? In the end this will give a good reason why one should think of the first Betti number as being the number of holes of thst space.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you'll want to assume is that $\Omega$ is connected.  Two disjoint disks, each with one point removed, is not homeomorphic to two disks where one has two points removed.

Comment: If $\Omega$ connected, it having only finitely many cylindrical ends is a necessary and sufficient condition. (So the complement of the cantor set is out, but most "reasonable" open sets are in, like the interiors of compact surfaces.)

Comment: I agree, but I am more interested in sufficient conditions